# Physical bluetooth signal blockers

Tags: sensors, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

What are some physical materials, such as metal plates, that are efficient at blocking out Bluetooth Low Energy signals?  If I have a BLE beacon sensor, how can I limit the sensor to receive signals from only one direction and not from the sides or behind the sensor?

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to block signals from other directions, you can reduce the strength of those signals from various directions with metal shielding.  Just as important as the materials is placement if them from the sensor and grounding the shielding material so it does not act as an antenna itself.  Specific instructions are difficult, as a lot depends on your physical environment.  Expect lots of trial and error.

A more reliable approach to the above is to get a BLE sensor with an antenna connector and attach a directional antenna pointing in the way you want to collect signals.

Comment: Have you experimented with any antenna's and could recommend any?  Any antenna the works in the 2.4GHz span will work right?

Comment: WiFi antennas are more common than Bluetooth ones, and since they are in the same frequency range they work well.  You can get panel WiFi antennas (typically about one square foot in size) that are strongly unidirectional.